# Blazor Server with Apache reverse proxy subdirectory - WebSockets not working

Tags: docker, websocket, server, blazor, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to run the standard Blazer Server demo (counter) in the following scenario:

- Containerized (Docker)
- Running on Debian 12
- Running behind an Apache reverse proxy in a virtual subdirectory

The app runs fine without the reverse proxy. E.g. when I use it directly specifying the container's port like http://myserver.example.local:8082/ The browser dev tools show that the websocket connection is used:

[image: Demo container with direct URL on port 8082]

The following Apache site config enables it to run in a subdirectory like http://myserver.example.local/sd/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine On

    <Location /sd/>

            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
            RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "ws://127.0.0.1:8082/?$1" [P,L]

            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8082/
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8082/

            ProxyHTMLURLMap http://127.0.0.1:8082 /sd/
            ProxyHTMLURLMap / /sd/
            SetOutputFilter  proxy-html

    </Location>
```

The counter works but it seems that the websocket connection can't be established and the app falls back into long polling. Each "Click Me" adds new Get requests as shown on the network tab:

[image: Demo container via proxy in subdirectory 'sd']

What can i do to enable websockets?

N.B. This is the Visual Studio standard demo without changes. I have also played around with an unchanged I have alerady played around with app.UsePathBase() and a <base> tag in _Host.cshtml but without success.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand why the configuration described above does not work - according to many examples, it should.

Anyhow, since Version 2.4.47 Apache has a new feature which works for me. You can now remove the Rewrite part and add 'upgrade=websocket' to the ProxyPass statement.

Here is a working config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Location /sd/>

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8082/ upgrade=websocket
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8082/

        ProxyHTMLURLMap http://127.0.0.1:8082 /sd/
        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /sd/
        SetOutputFilter  proxy-html

</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: At least I've upgraded to this new way without the rewrite which is good, and working. It's NOT that websockets do not work, because my other SignalR project does work with websockets, running in IIS behind Apache, no issues. It looks like it's Blazor specifically. You don't even see a websockets being tried, it just doesn't try. I would rather seen a failed connection.